# Is syscall an instruction on x86_64?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, machine-instruction

I wanted to check the code for performing system calls in glibc. I found something like this:

```
ENTRY (syscall)
    movq %rdi, %rax     /* Syscall number -> rax.  */
    movq %rsi, %rdi     /* shift arg1 - arg5.  */
    movq %rdx, %rsi
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    movq %r8, %r10
    movq %r9, %r8
    movq 8(%rsp),%r9    /* arg6 is on the stack.  */
    syscall         /* Do the system call.  */
    cmpq $-4095, %rax   /* Check %rax for error.  */
    jae SYSCALL_ERROR_LABEL /* Jump to error handler if error.  */
L(pseudo_end):
    ret         /* Return to caller.  */
```

Now my questions are:

1. Is `syscall` (before the `cmpq` instruction) an instruction?
2. If it is an instruction, what is the meaning of `ENTRY (syscall)`? The same name for an ENTRY (I don't know what an ENTRY is) and instruction?
3. What is `L(pseudo_end)`?

Comment: It is. It does the same as `int 0x80` in x86.

Comment: Note that normally specialized code is used for each system call, to set `%rax` from a constant (saving a register), and to skip setting up unused arguments.

Answer (score 39):

[`syscall`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) is an instruction in x86-64, and is used as part of the [ABI for making system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64).  (The 32-bit ABI uses `int 80h` or `sysenter`, and is also available in 64-bit mode, but using the 32-bit ABI from 64-bit code is a bad idea, especially for calls with pointer arguments.)

But there is also a [C library function named `syscall(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html), a generic wrapper for the system-call ABI.  Your code shows the dump of that function, including its decoding of the return value into `errno`-setting. `ENTRY(syscall)` just means that the function starts there.

`L()` and `ENTRY()` are CPP macros.

`L(pseudo_end)` is just a Label that can be a jump target.  Maybe the code at `SYSCALL_ERROR_LABEL` jumps back to there, although it would be more efficient for that block of code to just `ret`, so maybe it's a relic from a former version, or used for something else.

Comment: If this is an actual instruction, what is its opcode?

Comment: It is 0x0F 0x05 (just look at the software developer manual from Intel).

Comment: I wonder what would happen if a bare-metal program (i.e. without OS) call `syscall` instruction?

Comment: @Shuai, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_fault

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall.html

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `syscall` is an instruction on x86-64. There is a similar instruction `sysenter` on i686.

`ENTRY(syscall)` would be a macro. Probably expands to the symbol definition, you have to grep for that.